# How to call to mongodb inside my map/reduce functions? Is it a good practice?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I would like to know if:

- Firstly: Is it possible to use mongodb functions inside my map/reduce functions, for example:

  ```
  function() {
     foo = db.myCollection.find({ _id: ObjectId('4ee235ce002c62f393000008')})
     print(foo); # returns 'db.myCollection -> undefined'
  }
  ```
- Secondly: Is it a good practice? For example, I need to map a specific property from the documents referenced for a 'root' document.

Or maybe, can I set a habtm relationship on this specific property?

Thanks!

Comment: All of the functions that are available in the shell are probably available when doing map reduce but doing a query inside of a map/reduce is not really recommended. Can you provide some additional information about your query / problem you are trying to solve? Thanks K'ao.

Comment: Thanks to Mongoid, I have a habtm relationship, so inside my first document, I've got an array containing the object IDs of all documents referenced for this one. My goal is to map a specific property for each of these documents. I can have like 100.000+ documents referenced for an other, so I don't wanna do a "root.children.map(&:property)", the perfs wouldn't be really great… Hope this help to understand.

Answer (score 0):

although it is possible to call methods from the db object from MR, it is not recommended since it does not work properly with sharding.
With sharding you would only be able to access documents that are local to the shard.
If possible this kind of "joining" should be done client side.